# User 'dbo' does not have permission to run DBCC freesystemcache. AZURE

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I created SQL database on Azure. I tried to clear cache from SQL Server Management
using:

> DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('dbo')

Unfortunately  I am not successfull. 
I get the error

> User 'dbo' does not have permission to run DBCC freesystemcache.

How is this possible, as dbo is the owner of a database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @MJH stated in the previous answer, executing this requires ALTER SERVER STATE permissions. The article [DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freesystemcache-transact-sql) also clearly shows it **does not** apply to Azure SQL Database.

Since Azure SQL is a managed service, this will be handled by the platform.

Extra: see [ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of DBCC FREEPROCCACHE please try the following statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE
```

The ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION statement requires ALTER ANY DATABASE SCOPE CONFIGURATION permission on the database. This permission can be granted by a user with CONTROL permission on a database.